# Deallocate structure using pointer arithmetics and a pointer to an element of that structure

Tags: c++, structure, pointer-arithmetic

I have the following structure in C++ :

```
struct wrapper 
{
    // Param constructor
    wrapper(unsigned int _id, const char* _string1, unsigned int _year, 
         unsigned int _value, unsigned int _usage, const char* _string2)
         :
         id(_id), year(_year), value(_value), usage(_usage)
         {
             int len = strlen(_string1);
             string1 = new char[len + 1]();
             strncpy(string1, _string1, len);

             len = strlen(_string2);
             string2 = new char[len + 1]();
             strncpy(string2, _string2, len);
         };
    // Destructor
    ~wrapper()
         {
             if(string1 != NULL) 
                delete [] string1;
             if(string2 != NULL) 
                delete [] string2;
         }

    // Elements
    unsigned int     id;         
    unsigned int     year;       
    unsigned int     value;     
    unsigned int     usage; 
    char*            string1;    
    char*            string2;   
};
```

In main.cpp let's say I allocate memory for one object of this structure :

```
wrapper* testObj = new wrapper(125600, "Hello", 2013, 300, 0, "bye bye");
```

Can I now delete the entire object using pointer arithmetic and a pointer that points to one of the structure elements ?

Something like this :

```
void*  ptr = &(testObj->string2);

ptr -= 0x14;

delete (wrapper*)ptr;
```

I've tested myself and apparently it works but I'm not 100% sure that is equivalent to `delete testObj`.

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to delete  your `testObj`, you should just do `delete testObj;` and nothing else.

Comment: @Code-Guru : It was a structure element from my project code. I've remove it. Sorry

Comment: I'll just leave this here: `std::string`.

Comment: I'm surprised this even compiles, since `testObj` is not a pointer.

Comment: @DanielDumitrascu So the code you gave us is different than the code you are actually asking about?

Comment: Forgot to add "*", sorry

Comment: This is just a sample code, and I try to figure out if this method of deleting an object actually works.

Comment: You shouldn't need to "add" anything at all... What prevented you from posting the actual testcase that you're using?

Comment: What's `country`? Should it be `if(string1 != NULL) delete [] string1;`?. If so, that has exactly the same behaviour as `delete [] string1;`. Where did you learn to pointlessly test for null before deleting? Where did you learn to use `new char[]` and `delete[]` anyway? It smacks of a poor source of C++ knowledge. Try one of these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: I've removed that part, sorry for all this.

Comment: @DanielDumitrascu, this method works. please don't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I now delete the entire object using pointer arithmetic and a pointer that points to one of the structure elements ?

Theoretically, yes.

The pointer that you give to `delete` needs to have the correct value, and it doesn't really matter whether that value comes from an existing pointer variable, or by "adjusting" one in this manner.

You also need to consider the *type* of the pointer; if nothing else, you should cast to `char*` before performing your arithmetic so that you are moving in steps of single bytes. Your current code will not compile because `ISO C++ forbids incrementing a pointer of type 'void*'` (how big is a `void`?).

**However**, I recommend *not* doing this at all. Your magic number `0x14` is unreliable, given alignment and padding and the potential of your structure to change shape.

Instead, store a pointer to the actual object. Also stop with all the horrid memory mess, and use `std::string`. At present, your lack of copy constructor is presenting a nasty bug.

Comment: Only the threat of open nuclear warfare would persuade me to try any offset-bodges like this.

Comment: @Martin: Nuclear warfare is still preferable. That said, how about a nice game of chess?

Answer (score 3):

Technically, the code like this would work (ignoring the fact that `wrapper testObj` should be `wrapper* testObj` and that the offset is not necessarily `0x14`, e.g. debug builds sometimes pad the structures, and maybe some other detail I missed), but it is a horrible, horrible idea. I can't stress hard enough how horrible it is.

Instead of `0x14` you could use [`offsetof`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstddef/offsetof/) macro.

If you like spending nights in the company of the debugger, sure, feel free to do so.

I will assume that the reason for the question is sheer curiosity about whether it is possible to use pointer arithmetic to navigate from members to parent, and not that you would like to really do it in production code. Please tell me I am right.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, like you've said it's just curiosity :).

Comment: why not? maybe I missed something in the example

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic: Have you tried applying pointer arithmetic to a `void*`, lately? Read my answer.

Comment: ah, that. sure, that's exactly why I have phrased it as 'code like that' instead of 'that code', and glossed over other obvious errors (including 'some other detail I missed'). the point is that 'code like that' which uses pointer arithmetic to go from member to the parent and then deletes the object would indeed work.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do this sort of thing with pointer arithmetic. Whether you *should* is an entirely different story. Consider this macro (I know... I know...) that will give you the base address of a structure given its type, the name of a structure member and a pointer to that member:

```
#define ADDRESS_FROM_MEMBER(T, member, ptr) reinterpret_cast<T*>( \
  reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(ptr) - (ptrdiff_t)(&(reinterpret_cast<T*>(0))->member))
```